# .NET Collection for a 2d grid?

Tags: c#, .net

I am going to try my hat at programming a game.  My game will need to run the [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) path finding algorithm on a traditional game grid.

Like this for example: (S=Start, G=Goal, X=Wall)

```
-------------------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | G|  |
-------------------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
-------------------------------
|  | X| X| X| X|  |  |  |  |  |
-------------------------------
|  |  |  |  | X|  |  |  |  |  |
-------------------------------
| S|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
-------------------------------
```

To implement A*, I will need to be able to get the "neighbors" of any node. (For Example, Start has 3 neighbors (Above, Diagonal, and Right).)

The ways that come to mind to map this at a data layer is a 2 dimensional array or a linked list.

The array seems like the most performant and easy to pull off.  So if `S` was `[0][4]`, then its neighbors would be `[0 + 1][4]` (Right), `[0][4 - 1]` (Above), `[0 + 1][4 - 1]` (Diagonal)

But having done .NET application development for a few years, basic arrays seem a bit old school to me.

So before I go down that road, I thought I would ask if there is a nice .NET collection type I can use to map out a grid (at the data layer, not the UI).

Comment: Are you sure you want a Collection type? I would create my GameGrid class by wrapping an Array and creating indexed properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays sounds like the right choice in this case. Remember that most of the data structures provided are attempting to provide different functionality.

Given that the only abstract method you need (neighbors) is a quick implementation, there is no reason to use anything more complex as your basis.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to map out the whole grid. Far easier is to generate the neighbors for a given node on demand. i.e. Neighbors for a node (x,y) will be `{x-1, x, x+1} x {y-1, y, y+1} - (x, y)`. If any of these points lie outside the grid dimensions you do not consider them. If any of these locations have a wall, you ignore them also. So now you only have to consider how to efficiently check for walls in a location. Because the neighbors of a node can be found with the above method in this specific problem I do not think you need a adjacency list or a adjacency matrix here.

Edit:
On checking for walls at a location, I used to do it with a mapping from coordinates to an integer. i.e. `(x, y) => x + y*MaxWidth`. You get a unique integer for each coordinate. Now you only have to store the wall locations using that integer in a hashtable or something similar for efficient lookup. This method wins over the 2d array representation if the dimensions of the grid are fairly large.